# running a script to figure out which program is connecting to a specific url

Tags: python, tcp, scripting, monitoring, virus

This is an ad-hoc question, but here is the scenario. A family member ended up with a particular bit of virus that is connecting to a specific URL, the program masks itself as a executable through java run-time and creates voice popups upon startup. I done know if it is sending information or not.

I have switched through may AV software but none are able to detect it. Bit-defender was able to "stop" the url from making any connections. Thus I was able to find the exact URL.

My question is, if there a way for me to run a script(python or ruby) that tracks all incoming and out going TCP/IP connections and track it back to a particular program? Can you lead me in the right direction to where I might be able to code something like this?

Comment: Wouldn't wireshark be able to give you that info? https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: I will try it out and see what happens, I was looking more in to finding the program that was trying to connect that one particular URL

Comment: You could use requests to connect to the specific url. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/